# J4: General Config > Article Layout > Article Options switch: Switched to OFF also hides custom fields tabs

Tags: com-content

When I switch off the Arcticle options in **General Config > Article Layout > Article Options switch**  all tabs for my custom field group tabs are hidden as well. I don't want that.

Is there a way to hide the tabs:

- **Options**
- **Blog Options**

without affecting visibility of the others tabs?

I have tried with below custom CSS, but that did not have any effect.

```
#myTab > div:nth-child(1) > button:nth-child(2),
#myTab > div:nth-child(1) > button:nth-child(3) {
    display: none;
}
```

**Environment:**

- Joomla 4.0.4
- TinyMCE
- Joomshaper SP Page Builder

Comment: Welcome to JSE. You've written a good, clear question and provided proof that you tried to self-solve before asking for help.  Please take our [tour] while you wait for support.